# How to get process endpoints from CampaignResponse in AWS Pinpoint API

Tags: amazon-web-services, javadoc, aws-pinpoint

Here from the below screen, after creating a campaign in AWS Pinpoint, we get the Endpoints Targeted and Endpoints Delivered. I am similarly creating the campaign though the Pinpoint API but I am not getting these values in response.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-campaigns.html#CreateCampaign

[image: Screen After Campaign]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a separate API for this

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/AmazonPinpoint.html#getCampaignDateRangeKpi-com.amazonaws.services.pinpoint.model.GetCampaignDateRangeKpiRequest-

But this API is not real-time. The data is populated after 1 hour